# How to change background color in bootstrap switcher custom checkbox?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I've customized a checkbox in Bootstrap switcher plugin (https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch). How to make green color change to red on toggle?
Tried this:

```
$( ".bootstrap-switch" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" ); console.log('1111');
});
```

My example: http://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/JEOjjp

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the options `onColor` and / or `offColor`. 
First you have to define your `css` class this way:

```
.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-highlight {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Then you can add the option `onColor` or `offColor` in the initialization:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('onColor','highlight');
```

I tried in your sample code, but it worked not completely. I don't know, what you changed in the standard code of `bootstrap-switch`.

UPDATE

For setting both `onColor` and `offColor`, you can define it this way:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch(
'onColor':'highlight',
'offColor':'warning'
);
```

Comment: How do you define more than one parameter? I can set the OnColor or the OffColor but not both...

Comment: Please see my update in my answer. I never tried, but I think you can do it this way, can't you?